# How to interpret this scala syntax "Class[_ >: Float with Int with Double]"

Tags: scala, syntax, keyword, mxnet

When I read Mxnet source code, I was confused in following statements:

```
object NDArray {
  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[NDArray])
  private[mxnet] val DTYPE_NATIVE_TO_MX: Map[Class[_ >: Float with Int with Double], Int] = Map(
    classOf[Float] -> 0,
    classOf[Double] -> 1,
    classOf[Int] -> 4
  )
```

What does it mean for "Class[_ >: Float with Int with Double], Int]"?
I understand the scala keyword "with" could be used during class declaration, for example

```
Class person with glass {
```

means the class 'person' has the trait of objdect 'glass'.

How to interpret the usage of 'with' in above code?

Answer (score 2):

The `with` keyword is used for expressing [intersection types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Intersection_types).

The type `Float with Int with Double` is basically a subtype of `Float` and `Int` and `Double`. Of course you cannot have an actual value of this type because `Float`, `Int` and `Double` are all final classes. Here, in the type `Map[Class[_ >: Float with Int with Double], Int]`, it is used to express that every key of the `Map` has to be a `Class[T]` where `T` has to be a supertype of `Float with Int with Double`. And those supertypes are `Float`, `Int` and `Double` (and `AnyVal` and `Any`, if we go higher up the inheritance chain).

Comment: So could it also be a string, because String is a subtype of Any?

Comment: What could be a string? There are only `Class` objects here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the String class.

Comment: `Class` is invariant so normally not. `val c: Class[_ >: Float with Int with Double] = classOf[String]` doesn't compile.